# Does $S = \{ (2,1, 2), (-2,-1,2), (4,2,-4) \}$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was asked to find if  $S = \{ (2,1, 2), (-2,-1,2), (4,2,-4) \}$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I noticed that the Vector $(4,2,-4)$ is a multiple of the vector $(-2,-1,2)$ as $(4,2,-4) = -2(-2,-1,2)$ hence the determinant of the matrix formed by the vectors is 0.

So, does $S$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$?

My second question follows from this and it is if we are given a set of vectors and asked if they span a plane, space, R^4 and so on and we notice that the set of vectors are linearly dependent, please what can we say without computation, whether they span or not, just by observing the set of vectors are linearly dependent?
Thanks guys.
:-(
Confused Nel

Comment: Since others have answered your first question already so this is for your second question: Assuming you are in finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Given a set of $m$ vectors $\{v_1,v_2, \ldots , v_m\}$, this set can span a space of dimension no more than $m$. If you have one LD vector, then it will be at most $m-1$ and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Your question has a satisfactory answer that uses the notion of [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)).

> **Theorem.** Let $v_1,\dotsc,v_k\in\Bbb R^n$. Put $v_1,\dotsc,v_k$ into the columns of a matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}  v_1 & v_2 & \dotsb & v_k\end{bmatrix}$$Then $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_k\}$ spans $\Bbb R^n$ if and only if $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(A)=n$.

In your case, we have
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & -2 & 4 \\
1 & -1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & -4
\end{array}\right]
$$
Row-reducing gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref(A)=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
It follows that $\rank(A)=2\neq 3$. The theorem above then implies that the columns of $A$ do *not* span $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Since these vectors are linearly dependent, seeing as one row is a multiple of the other, we know that they do not span $\mathbb{R}^3$. In general, a set of vectors $\{v_{1},\dots,v_{n}\}$, any one of which is a linear combination of at least one of the other vectors, i.e. can be written as a multiple of one of the other vectors, are linearly dependent and will not span $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$S = \{ (2,1, 2), (-2,-1,2), (4,2,-4) \}$. Then $S$ generates vectors of the form:

$v=a(2,1, 2)+ b(-2,-1,2)+ c(4,2,-4)=a(2,1, 2)+[2c-b](2,1,-2)\\\space\space=a(2,1, 2)+d(2,1,-2)=(2a+2d,a+d,2a-2d)$

Here $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $2c-b=d$.

Now take $v=(1,0,0)$. Note that you can not find any solution for $a,d$ in this case, i.e. $(1,0,0)\notin \text{span}(S)$.

**Hence** $S$ do not span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

No, because $$(4,2,-4)=-2(-2,-1,2)$$